# input 2 arrays from keyboard and print value for each array

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I'm trying to create two empty integer arrays to hold up to 100 integers which is read from keyboard until the user enters `0` (zero). I need to print out the following:

1. The values entered for the first and second array
2. The values which occur in both arrays
3. The number of common to both arrays and the values of elements that are exclusive to one of the arrays.

So far I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CommonArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //int values2[] = new int[3];
        //int values2[] = new int[3];

        final int LENGTH = 100;

        int[] values = new int[LENGTH];
        //int currentSize = 0;
        fillArray(values);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



        for(int y: values)
        System.out.print(y);
        /*while(in.hasNextInt()){
            if(currentSize < values.length){
               values[currentSize] = in.nextInt();
               currentSize++;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++){
              System.out.println(values[i]);  
            }
        }
        **/

    }

    public static void fillArray(int x[])
    {
       for(int counter = 0; counter < x.length; counter++)
          x[counter]+=2;
    }

    public static void displayElement()
    {

    }

    public static void displayCommon()
    {

    }

    public static void displayNonCommon()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: That looks like a fine start to coding the problem you describe, do you have a question about a specific issue?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Seems you have started codding to the one method. Note, that Java is Object-Oriented language used to make objects and communicate with each other.